# In Microsoft SQL Server's linked server configuration, what does the "RPC" setting do?

Tags: sql-server

I'm **not** talking about "RPC Out". That setting works as I expect it to: when "false", I can't call stored procedures on my linked server. When it's "true", I can.

The specific option I am referring to is in the GUI (SQL Server Management Studio) on the Linked Server Properties window for any linked server (under "Server Options" on the left). Or, you may also set this option by calling sp_serveroption @optname='rpc'.

"RPC" can be set to either true or false. However, I can't find solid documentation on what this actually means in practice. I can't find any situation in my experimentation that behaves differently depending on whether "RPC" is set to true or false.

Can anyone give an example of what behaves differently depending on this setting?

Thanks!

Answer (score 4):

One allows A=>B the other allows B=>A.  In other words just because server A can call a proc on B doesn't mean B can call a proc on A.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186839.aspx

RPC
   Enables RPC **from** the specified server.

RPC Out
   Enables RPC **to** the specified server.

Comment: That makes sense in theory, except I couldn't find a scenario experimentally where the RPC setting had any effect. I created a linked server B on server A. However, the RPC setting seems to have no effect on server B calling server A. (That call happens via another linked server A defined on server B.)

Comment: I'm just guessing here but from what you posted... if A is linked to B from A, and B is linked to A from B then the links are going both ways through two different pipes.  The settings above likely only apply when A is linked to B on A ONLY.

Answer (score 2):

I know this is an old question but it returns as one of the first links on a search. I am just adding to @RThomas answer to give a bit more detail and when to use it. According to a [msdn blog](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/archive/blogs/jason_howell/what-is-the-rpc-and-rpc-out-option-on-a-sql-server-linked-server) the RPC vs RPC Out on a SQL Server linked-server is this:

1. RPC - This setting is mainly for legacy feature called [Remote Server](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/database-engine/configure-windows/remote-servers?view=sql-server-ver16). According to the blog it states you will not be using this in SQL Server 2005 and higher. Unless you get an error like:

> 18482 “Could not connect to server '%.*ls' because '%.*ls' is not defined as a remote server. Verify that you have specified the correct server name. %.*ls.”

2. RPC Out - setting is very pertinent to linked servers on SQL Server 2005 and higher. If this is not enabled you can get the following error message:

> Msg 7411, Level 16, State 1, Line 1  Server 'myLinkedServer' is not configured for RPC.

Which really should say **RPC *Out*** should be enabled.